# PHP database connection class

Tags: php, mysql, class

I am trying to get a users ID from a database within a class, but I have very little to no experience with classes, how could I go about getting the uid from the DB and then return the uid?

so basically something like this,

```
class hello {
   public function getUid(){
      //connect to the db
      //get all of the users info
      $array = mysql_fetch_array($result);
      $uid = $array['uid'];

      return $uid;
   }
}
```

Like I said, I am still new to classes, so any advice or help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

First build a MySQL class library... suiting the requirements like in this sample piece:

```
<?php

include '../config/Dbconfig.php';

class Mysql extends Dbconfig {

    public $connectionString;
    public $dataSet;
    private $sqlQuery;
    
    protected $databaseName;
    protected $hostName;
    protected $userName;
    protected $passCode;

    function Mysql() {
        $this -> connectionString = NULL;
        $this -> sqlQuery = NULL;
        $this -> dataSet = NULL;

        $dbPara = new Dbconfig();
        $this -> databaseName = $dbPara -> dbName;
        $this -> hostName = $dbPara -> serverName;
        $this -> userName = $dbPara -> userName;
        $this -> passCode = $dbPara ->passCode;
        $dbPara = NULL;
    }
  
    function dbConnect()    {
        $this -> connectionString = mysql_connect($this -> serverName,$this -> userName,$this -> passCode);
        mysql_select_db($this -> databaseName,$this -> connectionString);
        return $this -> connectionString;
    }

    function dbDisconnect() {
        $this -> connectionString = NULL;
        $this -> sqlQuery = NULL;
        $this -> dataSet = NULL;
        $this -> databaseName = NULL;
        $this -> hostName = NULL;
        $this -> userName = NULL;
        $this -> passCode = NULL;
    }

    function selectAll($tableName)  {
        $this -> sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM '.$this -> databaseName.'.'.$tableName;
        $this -> dataSet = mysql_query($this -> sqlQuery,$this -> connectionString);
        return $this -> dataSet;
    }

    function selectWhere($tableName,$rowName,$operator,$value,$valueType)   {
        $this -> sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM '.$tableName.' WHERE '.$rowName.' '.$operator.' ';
        if($valueType == 'int') {
            $this -> sqlQuery .= $value;
        }
        else if($valueType == 'char')   {
            $this -> sqlQuery .= "'".$value."'";
        }
        $this -> dataSet = mysql_query($this -> sqlQuery,$this -> connectionString);
        $this -> sqlQuery = NULL;
        return $this -> dataSet;
        #return $this -> sqlQuery;
    }


    function insertInto($tableName,$values) {
        $i = NULL;

        $this -> sqlQuery = 'INSERT INTO '.$tableName.' VALUES (';
        $i = 0;
        while($values[$i]["val"] != NULL && $values[$i]["type"] != NULL) {
            if($values[$i]["type"] == "char") {
                $this -> sqlQuery .= "'";
                $this -> sqlQuery .= $values[$i]["val"];
                $this -> sqlQuery .= "'";
            }
            else if($values[$i]["type"] == 'int') {
                $this -> sqlQuery .= $values[$i]["val"];
            }
            $i++;
            if($values[$i]["val"] != NULL)  {
                $this -> sqlQuery .= ',';
            }
        }
        $this -> sqlQuery .= ')';
        #echo $this -> sqlQuery;
        mysql_query($this -> sqlQuery,$this ->connectionString);
        return $this -> sqlQuery;
        #$this -> sqlQuery = NULL;
    }

    function selectFreeRun($query) {
        $this -> dataSet = mysql_query($query,$this -> connectionString);
        return $this -> dataSet;
    }

    function freeRun($query) {
        return mysql_query($query,$this -> connectionString);
    }
}
?>
```

and the configuration file...

```
<?php
class Dbconfig {
    protected $serverName;
    protected $userName;
    protected $passCode;
    protected $dbName;

    function Dbconfig() {
        $this -> serverName = 'localhost';
        $this -> userName = 'root';
        $this -> passCode = 'pass';
        $this -> dbName = 'dbase';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: FYI: When you are using this code make sure you are validating the data from the queries, as this will allow SQL injection. Still, I like the approach even after the years :)

Answer (score 10):

Alright, one piece of advice:

**Do everything for a reason. Don't use things you don't know. Go and learn them instead.**

One may give you an answer for this specific question, but until you don't know what **[Object Oriented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming)** means and why there are **[classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class-based_programming)** at all, you shouldn't use them.

Comment: Thanx for the advice! At the moment I am learning as I go, which is why I needed some help.

Answer (score 5):

You can use custom database class.
**Code :**

```
<?php 
Class Database
{
    private $user ;
    private $host;
    private $pass ;
    private $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->user = "root";
        $this->host = "localhost";
        $this->pass = "";
        $this->db = "db_blog";
    }
    public function connect()
    {
        $link = mysql_connect($this->user, $this->host, $this->pass, $this->db);
        return $link;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

- Create two classes. One for working with database, second one for managing User or Auth data.
- For SQL class create methods connect(), query(), fetch() etc
- For User class create methods get($id) etc

Answer (score 4):

There is a problem with the way your code is written, not with the class. Take a closer look at this line:

```
$array = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

This is the first time variable `$result` appears on the function. Therefore, it is not possible to communicate with the database.

A possible pseudo-code would be:

- connect to the DB server
- query the database
- fetch the results
- return the `uid` field.

Have a look at the relevant documentation first:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 3):

Try following:

```
ini_set("display_errors", 'off');
    ini_set("error_reporting",E_ALL);   

class myclass {
    function myclass()   {    
        $user = "root";
        $pass = "";
        $server = "localhost";
        $dbase = "";

           $conn = mysql_connect($server,$user,$pass);
           if(!$conn)
        {
            $this->error("Connection attempt failed");
        }
        if(!mysql_select_db($dbase,$conn))
        {
            $this->error("Dbase Select failed");
        }
        $this->CONN = $conn;
        return true;
    }
    function close()   {   
        $conn = $this->CONN ;
        $close = mysql_close($conn);
        if(!$close)
        {
            $this->error("Connection close failed");
        }
        return true;
    }       function sql_query($sql="")   {    
        if(empty($sql))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(empty($this->CONN))
        {
            return false;
        }
        $conn = $this->CONN;
        $results = mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die("Query Failed..<hr>" . mysql_error());
        if(!$results)
        {   
            $message = "Bad Query !";
            $this->error($message);
            return false;
        }
        if(!(eregi("^select",$sql) || eregi("^show",$sql)))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            $count = 0;
            $data = array();
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))
            {
                $data[$count] = $row;
                $count++;
            }
            mysql_free_result($results);
            return $data;
         }
    }      
} 
$obj = new myclass();
$obj->sql_query("");
```