# Why not use a database function class in php

Tags: php, mysql, function

I adopted code given in this example: [PHP database connection class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228694/php-database-connection-class)

But i changed the code with the link above and it is as follows:

```
class Database {
    public function connect() {
        define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
        define('DB_NAME', 'university');
        define('DB_USER', 'root');
        define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
        $db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
    }
}
function Information(){
    Database::connect();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE id "; $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo $row['name'];
        }
}
Information();
```

It gives error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: db in /Applications/XAMPP/file.php on line 12.
```

What could be the reason and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$db` belongs in the `connect()` function scope. Why not treat `$db` as a class property instead and access it via `$class->db`?

Comment: `WHERE id ` ?? think it would also be useful to show errors. To get errors out of PHP even in a LIVE environment add these 4 lines to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a property that all methods can share:

```
<?php

class Database 
{
    private $db;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
        define('DB_NAME', 'university');
        define('DB_USER', 'root');
        define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
        $this->db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
    }

    public function query($sql)
    {
        return mysqli_query($this->db, $query);
    }
}
```

And then refactor your function

```
function Information()
{
    $db = new Database();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM student WHERE id "; 
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
         echo $row['name'];
    }
}

Information();
```

Answer (score -1):

The variable `db` is unknown to the function on this line:

Since `$db`is a class property, just create it as a variable in the class

```
 private $db;
```

and set it in the connect function as mentioned by `delboy1978uk` like this:

```
$this->db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
```

Comment: Your solution will not work as you call `connect()` statically. `$this` won't wiork

Comment: @delboy1978uk updated it